# Android Chrome Beta - Splash Screens from Homescreen

Tags: android, google-chrome, homescreen, progressive-web-apps

My website does not show the new splash screen (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen) when loading from homescreen, although I linked a manifest. Therefore I believe, I made an invalid manifest.

Here is the index.php code:

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="sharedcode/webappmanifest.json">
```

And here is the complete webappmanifest.json code:

```
{
  "short_name": "Igel100",
  "name": "Igel100",
  "start_url": "./?utm_source=web_app_manifest",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/projekte/igel100/data/webappicon.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
  ],
  "background_color": "#9fa8da",
  "theme_color": "#ccccff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "any"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface it the manifest looks ok, here are a couple of things that you can also check:

- Suggest you add a 192x192 image, it is the closest to 48dp at the highest screen density (4x)
- Ensure that when you added the icon to the homescreen it was done **after** Chrome supported splash-screen.  If you added it before we can't update the homescreen entry, thus it won't appear. Essentially try to add to homescreen again and it should work.

Comment: Adding more images sizes solved the problem. Thanks for this helpful suggestion.